# non-existent MySites opened instead of userdisp.aspx

Tags: 2010, user-profile, sharepoint-server, userprofiles

I have encountered a very strange problem. 
This is the scenario:

On this particular farm, there is no MySiteHost specified. Upon clicking a user the userdisp.aspx opens and displays the basic information.

Except for one user. For this particular user the link point to the userdisp.aspx, although it redirects the request to `http://machine/my/Person.aspx`, which then fails.

Crawling the logs hints me at this Access denied exception:

```
01/22/2014 15:36:00.93  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy... 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.93* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        ....Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock) 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.93  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous... 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.93* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        ...)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()    4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.94  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy... 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.94* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        ....Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock) 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.94  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous... 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.94* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        ...)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()    4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.95  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy... 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.95* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        ....Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock) 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.95  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous... 4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.95* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        ...)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()    4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.95  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0E90  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   d22b    High        Failure retrieving application ID for User Profile Application Proxy 'User Profile Service Application': Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_AppID()   4befd48c-63f0-41ae-a255-d2304aa9d07a
01/22/2014 15:36:00.96  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy... 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.96* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        ....Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock) 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.96  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous... 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.96* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        ...)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()    1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.97  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy... 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.97* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        ....Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock) 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.97  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous... 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.97* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        ...)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()    1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.98  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy... 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.98* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   hyc6    High        ....Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock) 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
01/22/2014 15:36:00.98  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x08C0)                       0x0CF8  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous... 1520f07a-fef3-4467-bc9a-baa8ce51d906
```

...which makes no sense to me.

Any help is deeply appreciated.